# remove all text from node using domxpath

Tags: php, dom, domxpath

I am trying to remove all text from node, but when I am removing text, it removes normal text not from table text and inner div's text.

Here is my code:

```
$dom    = new DOMDocument();
$result = $dom->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
//$nodes = $finder->query('//div[starts-with(@id, "post_message_")]');
$nodes = $finder->query('//div[contains(text(), "") and .//img and .//a and starts-with(@id, "post_message_")]');
```

But it gives me this html in node:

```
<div id="post_message_31962189">.<br><div align="center"><img src="http://s3.postimage.odf.jpg" border="0" alt=""></div><br><b><div align="center"><font size="5"><font color="Blue"><br><br>
WATERMARKED <br><br>
ADDED 4  IN LAST PAGE<br><br></font></font></div></b><br>
=============================================================================<br>
     IN HOTEL  <br><br><b><font size="4"><font color="Red">  i promise        </font></font></b><br><br><b><div align="center"><font size="5"><font color="Blue">ADDED 4 NEW </font></font></div></b><br><br><br><a href="http://asd.sd./tml8rfg4" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Ashoka hotel</a><br><br><br><br><img src="http:/img.jpg" border="0" alt=""></div>
```

I want to remove all the things except img a and br.

Comment: Rather than removing everything you don't want, have you tried extracting the stuff you do want?

Comment: Actually all the things inside message div,  So how i can retrieve that?

Comment: I tried with your suggestion, But all data massed-up, Data not showing correctly. So trying to inner div if it has. Any suggestion?